# What does "darkvision with a range of 120 feet" mean in the Shadow sorcerer's Eyes of the Dark feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, sorcerer, vision-and-light

The Eyes of the Dark feature says:

> Starting at 1st level, you have darkvision with a range of 120 feet.

Does that mean 120 feet of normal vision (shades of gray) in dark and another 120 feet in dim light?

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I've never thought about this *nor* had it come up

Comment: @medix2 yeah it just came to me

Answer (score 12):

### Darkvision effectively makes dim light bright, and darkness dim light; the total range here is 120 feet.

The section on "[Darkvision](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Darkvision)" states:

> A monster with darkvision can see in the dark within a specific radius. The monster can see in dim light **within the radius** as if it were bright light, and in darkness as if it were dim light. The monster can't discern color in darkness, only shades of gray. Many creatures that live underground have this special sense.

There is only one range and depending on the sort of lighting in that range, the creature can see differently. An 40-foot radius of darkness followed by an area of dim light would appear as a 40-foot radius of dimly lit grey, and beyond that brightly lit color.

The sort of doubles radius thing is often used with light sources like a [Torch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/torch):

> A torch burns for 1 hour, providing bright light in a 20-foot radius and dim light for an additional 20 feet. If you make a melee attack with a burning torch and hit, it deals 1 fire damage.

For another example of something with one radius, there is the [*darkness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/darkness) spell:

> Magical darkness spreads from a point you choose within range to fill a 15-foot-radius sphere for the duration [...]

Comment: So a total of 120 feet?

Comment: Ah, yes, somehow forgot to actually say that XD

Comment: I always thought normal player darkvision was 60 feet plus 60 feet like a torch. I saw that months ago as the description on dnd beyond when I was making a character